# retrofit2.Converter for handling error messages

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

Is there any way to implement on Retrofit a Converter for handling the body of an 40x error?

I'm having issues with responses from the server that have 40x code and empty body message, every time it returns and EOFException.

I have implemented a Converter but when it has 40x error it does not go through it.

Retrofit:

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();    
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                 .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(url);
            builder.client(okHttpClientBuilder.build());
```

this is where I handle error from Server calls:

```
public static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> parseHttpErrors() {

    return observable -> observable.onErrorResumeNext(
            (Throwable throwable) -> {


                if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {

                    int errorCode = ((HttpException) throwable).response().code();

                    return validateHttpExceptions(throwable, errorCode);

                } else if (throwable instanceof IOException) {

                    return Observable.error(new NetworkException());
                }
                return Observable.error(throwable);
            });
}

private static <T> ObservableSource<? extends T> validateHttpExceptions(Throwable throwable, int errorCode) {

    switch (errorCode) {
        case 401:// Request Unauthorized
            return Observable.error(new CredentialsException());
        case 408:// Request Timeout
            return Observable.error(new NetworkException());
        default:
            return Observable.error(new UnknownHttpException(errorCode, throwable.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

And a single server call

```
service.doAction(params)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .compose(NetworkErrorHandler.parseHttpErrors())
        .map(data -> {

         //map data
        return data;
        });
```

Comment: Are you using RxJava?

Comment: Yes I do, RxJava 2

Comment: Se this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295237/rxjava-retrofit-parse-api-error-for-user/46302070#46302070

Comment: I have something similar with onErrorResumeNext. Problem here is that when I catch the Exception is not HttpException but EOFException. So I cannot handle properly a 403 error for example.

Comment: I think answer is posted here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1554#issuecomment-178633697

Comment: That's the one I've used but it does not go through it when there's an error. For 200 code messages perfect, but not for 4xx errors

Comment: @JoseMLechoncan can you post some relevant code. if possible a test url to test?

Comment: @JoseMLechoncan can you post some relevant code. if possible a test url to test?

Comment: @Raghunandan just added it.

Comment: what happens with this is that I don't get a HttpException but an EOFException. so it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found what was producing this error. It was **HttpLoggingInterceptor**. After removing it no longer had EOFException.

Comment: That's interesting. Have you tried to use Stetho instead?

Comment: Good point, I did use it time ago but not for network. Thanks!